# unittest for custom errors

Tags: python, unit-testing, custom-errors

I have three different files:

A class file lang.py that has the following function

```
from errors import StatusCodeError
class LangModel:
    def __init__(self, localpath2fst, host="127.0.0.1", port="5000", logfile="log"):
        ...
    def state_update(self):
        """
        Initialize the language model (on the server side)
        """
        try:
            r = requests.post(
            'http://' +
            self.host +
            ':' +
            self.port +
            '/init')
        except requests.ConnectionError:
            raise ConnectionErr(self.host, self.port)
        if not r.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
            raise StatusCodeError(r.status_code)
```

An error file errors.py:

```
class StatusCodeError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, status_code):
        self.dErrArgs = status_code
        Exception.__init__(
            self,
            "Connection was not established and has status code {0}".format(self.dErrArgs))
```

and a third file test.py

```
import unittest
from lang import LangModel
from errors import StatusCodeError

class TestPreLM(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_incorrect_input(self):
     """
     confirm the process provides
     an error given an incorrect
     input
     """
     abs_path_fst = os.path.abspath("a valid path")
     # local fst
     localfst = abs_path_fst
     # init LMWrapper
     lmodel = LangModel(
      localfst,
      host='127.0.0.1',
      port='5000',
      logfile="lmwrap.log")
      # try to get priors
      with self.assertRaises(StatusCodeError):
         lmodel.state_update(['3'])
```

Oddly enough when I have the test code found within the class file, the test succeeds but when it is found in isolation (in test.py) the test fails and I'm unsure why. If you can lighten my way I'll be happy ;)

Comment: `lmodel.state_update(['3'])`, where is `state_update` defined?

Comment: Thanks, I fixed my reduced example. I found that I had to add sys.path referring to the dir in which lang.py and error.py we located. So, I solved it, and thanks for helping me :-) (even if it was adding this comment)